# Automator list of urls - no results

Tags: macos, automator, data-transfer, url

I have a list of URLs as input, and I'm trying to get image on the pages in order to download them. I'm filtering the text and passing it to the 'Get Image URLs from Webpage' action, but it's not receiving anything. Am I missing a step, or have something set wrong. Every reference I've found indicates that this should work.

[image]

Comment: I'm on 10.8.2, Automator 2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using "Get Specified Text" then filtering paragraphs, you can use "Get Specified URLs" and direct this straight to Get Image URLs from Webpage:

[image]

Alternatively, if you want to parse text, you can use Extract URLs from Text:

[image]

<sup>[Download Workflow](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1mxzk48vmm6nxo7/Images%20from%20URLs.workflow.zip)</sup>

Comment: That won't accept a list, though. I will ultimately need to run this on a large list of URLs.

Comment: @RBrandon Ah, ok — see edit for second method that allows text input.

Comment: Perfect. I hadn't come across the extract action. Thanks.