# How to add a timer between wget html downloads?

Tags: xcode, automator

I found this very useful script that does the job for what I'm looking to achieve.

It's been taken from this post: [Batch download URLs from a .txt file](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/214238/batch-download-urls-from-a-txt-file)

> To use the following method, you will need to install wget.
>        Make a file with the extension .sh in the same directory as your file containing the links and add this text to it:
>
> ```
> mkdir ~/Desktop/download
>
> while read line; do wget -E -H --directory-prefix=/Users/username/Desktop/download -k -p $line; done < file.txt
>
> cd ~/Desktop/download
> ```
>
> Make sure to edit the script and change username to your username
>        This reads file.txt for the URLs and runs the wget command multiple times with all the links one-by-one and saves them to a
>   folder named download on your desktop.

I just need to make a small edit to make sure that between one request and another the script waits 5 minutes.

Could you please tell me how to edit it?

Answer (score 1):

`wget` can read URLs directly from a file (`-i file`), and knows how to pause between downloads (`-w seconds`), so you don’t actually need a loop at all. Also, `wget` downloads into the current directory by default so you don't really need `--directory-prefix` either.

Just run

```
mkdir -p ~/Desktop/download
cd ~/Desktop/download
wget -E -H -k -p -w $((5*60)) -i file.txt
```

PS: You might also want to add `--random-wait` to have `wget` wait between 0.5 and 1.5 times the number of seconds you've specified. This might help to avoid problems with sites who take extreme steps to detect and block `wget` requests.